# Combine Rarely Used Factor Levels Across all Factors in Data Frame

Tags: r, forcats

I would like to combine factor levels that are used fewer than 5 times for each factor in a dataset containing many different factors. While I understand that the fct_lump() function in the forcats package can help me achieve this for a single factor, is there a function where I can apply the fct_lump() function over all the factors in my dataset?

Answer (score 1):

We can check whether the column is `factor` with `mutate_if` and apply `fct_lump`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df1 %>%
     mutate_if(is.factor, fct_lump)
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
i1 <- sapply(df1, is.factor)
df1[i1] <- lapply(df1[i1], fct_lump)
```